# How to add another page ID in a PHP function - newbie asking?

Tags: php

I need some help to see where I am going wrong.

I am trying to add a page ID to this original function:

```
<?php if( $post->ID != '91' )
    {
        get_sidebar();
    } ?>
>
```

to also exclude the ID 1267. 
I am trying this, with no success.

```
<?php
    $pageIDs_to_exclude=array("91","1267");

    if( $post->ID != $pageIDs_to_exclude )
    {
        get_sidebar();
    }
?>
```

Surely there must be a better way of doing this?  Or what am I missing?
Thnaks for any help
/Anders

Comment: You cant compare directly to an array. You have to loop through it.

Comment: Thank you to all who took the time to answer me. You have been most helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to directly compare `$post->ID` to `$pageIDs_to_exclude`, an array. As `$post->ID` is not an array (it is a string), this is not possible. Instead, see if `$post->ID` is in `$pageIDs_to_exclude`.

```
if (!in_array($post->ID, $pageIDs_to_exclude)) {

    get_sidebar();

}
```

`in_array()` is a function that will return `true` if the object is found in the array.

Comment: Thank you for not only the code, but the explanation in terms that even I can understand (somewhat).

Answer (score 5):

```
$pageIDs_to_exclude = array("91","1267");

// in_array will return false if it doesn't find $post->ID within the $pageIDs_to_exclude array 
if( ! in_array($post->ID, $pageIDS_to_exclude) )
{
    get_sidebar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in_array of php. It will return true or false.

```
$pageIDs_to_exclude=array("91","1267");

if(!in_array($post->ID,$pageIDs_to_exclude))
{
    get_sidebar();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the PHP function `in_array()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to search for a value in an array:

```
<?php
  $page_ids = array("91", "1271");
  if(!in_array($post->ID, $page_ids))
   {
    get_sidebar();
   }
?>
```